# Spin Google Maps Satellite View Programatically

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a project where I need to load a [Google Map](https://www.google.com/maps/@28.3433826,-77.852534,11447201m/data=!3m1!1e3) in satellite view and mimic the opening of Google Earth by spinning the globe smoothly.

I have been in the v3 docs for some time today without seeing any methods for spinning the globe.

Can anyone connect me with the documentation (or an example) of spinning the globe via the v3 API?

Comment: Google Maps API doesn't support globe map type. Are you looking for a workaround?

Comment: @GökhanKurt yes I am.  Maybe something that simulates a click and drag like a person can execute at https://www.google.com/maps/@-47.8271089,-139.0489891,22971709m/data=!3m1!1e3

Comment: What you are asking is not something trivial. First of all, maps api tiles are drawn with html images. Drawing a globe would require you to implement a projection of tile images on to globe and rendering it on canvas. After you have implemented those, you can ask for how to spin it. Otherwise you are asking someone to write project that would take atleast man-weeks.

Comment: @GökhanKurt - thank you.  This is what I thought having looked for a solution.  I appreciate the reply.

Comment: You can archive this by using open street maps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, google maps don't have this functionality. But you can do it by changing css property `transform: rotate([angle]deg);`

```js
var mapOptions={
  zoom: 8,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(52, 1),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
};
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),mapOptions);

var angle=0;
setInterval(function(){
  document.getElementById('map').style.transform='rotate('+angle+'deg)';
  angle++;
  if(angle==360){
    angle=0;
  }
},50);
```

```css
#wrapper{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#map{
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  top: -100px;
  right: -100px;
  bottom: -100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#BasicMapTypes

Comment: This is somewhat close to what I need but I have to present satellite view like this link and rotate like a globe. https://www.google.com/maps/@14.5497904,-80.7789379,11469636m/data=!3m1!1e3

Comment: Thank you for your update.  I was not alerted to your changes.  I have started a 500 pt bounty which I will award to your answer when allowed in 23 hours.

Comment: 500 Bounty awarded.  Thank you for your help.